# Too many imageview ; outofmemory error

Tags: android, imageview, png, out-of-memory

I am making an application which has to inflate layout as below with 40 **image-view** each displaying a png file. The XML code of the layout file is below. The layout contains images files that will be replaced by other image-view that are taken from camera later when the user takes those picture.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texViewAssignAlphabets"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/LightGrey"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_icon_image"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:text="@string/letter_assign"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="6" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewA"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_a" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewB"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_b" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewC"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_c" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewD"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_d" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewE"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_e" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewF"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_f" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="6" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewG"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_g" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewH"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_h" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewI"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_i" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewJ"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_j" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewK"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_k" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewL"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_l" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="6" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewM"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_m" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewN"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_n" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewO"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_o" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewP"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_p" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewQ"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_q" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewR"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_r" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="6" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewS"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_s" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewT"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_t" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewU"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_u" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_v" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewW"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_w" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewX"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_x" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="6" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewY"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_y" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewZ"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_z" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewAwithDoubleDotabove"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_a_withdoubledotsabove" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewOWithDoubleDotAbove"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_o_withdoubledotsabove" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewAWithCircleAbove"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_a_circleabove" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewDot"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_dot" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="6" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewExclaim"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_exclamation" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewLetterDash"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_dash" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView0"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_0" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_2" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_3" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="6" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_4" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_5" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_6" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_7" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_8" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/letter_9" />
        </TableRow>



    </TableLayout>

     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="15dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.05"
         android:background="@color/LightGrey"
         android:gravity="left"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageViewPhotoJustCropped"
             android:layout_width="50dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             android:contentDescription="@string/desc_icon_image" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/OkButton"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
             android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
             android:contentDescription="@string/desc_icon_image"
             android:minHeight="30dp"
             android:minWidth="40dp"
             android:text="@string/ok_btn" 
             android:visibility="gone"/>

    </RelativeLayout>



        </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that when I try to set this layout in the activity . It gives me out of memory error. I know that it is because of the memory leak due to huge number of images that I have been using. I solved the problem by reducing image size nearly 50% less(ie if 2 kb then reducing to 1 kb).

The problem now is that the resolution of these images is so low that it does not look very good. If you have any idea on how to solve this issue then it would be really helpful. I have already read the document about handling bitmap and tried few suggestions mentioned here at stackoverflow but without any good result. Thank you in advance.

Comment: try and use image lazy loader like Picasso

Comment: i am sorry but i did not get what you mean ?

Comment: You should better use a gridView and reuse your imageViews in its adapter.

Comment: i have tried gridview  too. but still it gives me same error and works when i reduce the size.

Comment: From layout it seems you are implementing something like software keyboard, so you need all views displayed at once. Which device gives you error?

Comment: I was talking about using an external library that will lazy load your images , and you should look into using the GridView

Comment: @1011 here is a link to a library for the loading : http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: I am using HTC One / Kit Kat

Answer (score 0):

may try to load your images into your site and change every "imageView" with "WebView" and upload each image like this:

```
webview001=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview001);
WebSettings webSettings1 = webview001.getSettings();
webSettings1.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings1.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview001.loadData("<html><head><style type='text/css'>body{margin:auto auto;text-align:center;} img{width:100%25;} </style></head><body><img src='http://yourimageurlposition'/></body></html>" ,"text/html",  "UTF-8");
```

or try to use more memory on your device by adding in your Manifest.xml this line

```
<application
       .....
       ......
        android:largeHeap="true" >
```

Comment: this does not answer my question , so not accepting as answer !!

Answer (score 0):

Use something that takes an adapter, like [gridview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) or [listview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)....

Views that take an adapter load data dynamically for the childviews that are on the screen.   Your app is out of memory because you're loading all 40 images at once.

Bitmaps take a lot of memory, make sure you are also not loading more data than you need for the image size.  i.e. don't load data for a full screen image, when you're app is only showing a thumbnail.  You can review the android guide on loading large bitmaps efficiently [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).